# where the segmentation fault is generated in this code?

Tags: c++

```
class Transaction  //TO store a transaction read from file
{
public:
    int maxlenth;
    int length1,length2;
    vector<string> *items;
    vector<int>  *share; 
    int tmv;

    Transaction():maxlenth(Translen),length1(0),length2(0)
    {
        items=new vector<string>(maxlenth);
        share=new vector<int>(maxlenth);
    }
    ~Transaction()    
    {
        delete items;
        delete share;
    }

    void set_tmv()
    {
        tmv=0;
        for(int i=0;i<=length2;i++)
               tmv=tmv+(*share)[i];
    }     
};


class Data
{
public:
    ifstream in;

    Data(char *filename);
    ~Data();

    Transaction& getnextTransaction(Transaction &Trans);
};


Data::Data(char *filename)
{
    ifstream in(filename);
        assure(in,filename);
}

Data::~Data()
{
    in.close(); 
}

Transaction&  Data::getnextTransaction(Transaction &Trans)
{
    const char* delimiters =
          "  \t;()\"<>:{}[]+-=&*#.,/\\~";

    //ifstream in("testdata.txt");
    //set<string>Items1;
    vector<string> v(5);
    int i=0;
    string line;
    getline(in, line); 

    char* s =strtok((char*)line.c_str(), delimiters);
    while(s) 
    {
        if(i==v.size())
            v.resize(v.size()*2);

        v[i++]=s;
        s = strtok(0, delimiters);
    }
    vector<string>::iterator it=v.begin();
    int j=0;
    while(j<50)
    {
        (*Trans.items)[(Trans.length1)++]=v[j];
        j=j+2;
    }
    j=1;
    while(j<=50)
    {
        (*Trans.share)[Trans.length2++]=(atoi(v[j].c_str()));
        j=j+2;
    }

    //copy(v.begin(),v.end(),ostream_iterator<string>(cout,"\n");
    return Trans;
}

int main()
{
    Data d("testdata.txt");
    Transaction t,q;

    d.getnextTransaction(t);
    t.set_tmv();

    return 0;
}
```

While I am debugging with gdb, I am geting something like:

> Programm recieved SIGSEGV segmentation fault in std::string::assign(std::string const &)

While I am including the line `ifstream in("testdata.txt")` in function `getNexttransaction()`, I am not getting any error.

What's going wrong?

Comment: I don't think the error comes from there, but make sure to use the `const char*` type for string literals, as in `Data`'s constructor.

Comment: what does bt (in gdb) prints after the segfault?

Comment: You *really* want to define a copy constructor and assignment operator for this class or they're going to cause you all sorts of headaches when they are implicitly called.

Comment: Would be nice to actually have code that compiles...You're missing any explaination of `Translen` and `assure` and a bunch of includes.

Answer (score 4):

well, i did not read your code so i dont know what its purpose is, but if its an usual c++ application and nothing to modify the systems default memory management, you should learn using GDB.

http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/gdbsegfault.html

helps a lot removing those nasty segfaults, it will just take you 5 minutes to read it and use it, but can save you hours of printf debugging.
(sorry but reading through that much code to find a wrong reference to some memory would be hard-work)

Answer (score 2):

How can you be absolutely sure that your vector `v` will have 50 elements in it, and no amount that is less?  In this while-loop,

```
while(j<50)
{
  (*Trans.items)[(Trans.length1)++]=v[j];
  j=j+2;
}
```

you're accessing up to 50 members for the vector `v` since you're making calls to `v[j]`, and `j` will go up to 49, but if `v.size() != 50`, then you're going to get a segmentation fault.  Since you initialize `v` to be only 5 elements, and only resize it if you increment past it's current max-size, that means will have at least 5 or more members in `v`, but that does not mean there will be at least 50 members.  The same is true for the second while-loop using the value of `j` as well.

Answer (score 1):

After hacking the code a bit so that it would compile. I get this from valgrind:

```
bash> valgrind ./a.out

Invalid read of size 4
==1827==    at 0xDE038: std::string::assign(std::string const&) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.0.4.dylib)
==1827==    by 0x282B: Data::getnextTransaction(Transaction&) (dummy.cpp:88)
==1827==    by 0x2947: main (dummy.cpp:110)
==1827==  Address 0x3ec6d8 is 4 bytes after a block of size 20 alloc'd
==1827==    at 0x1A6BB: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:261)
```

Line 88 is right inside your main read loop. Suggesting that your loop may be confused.

This may not be your problem. (As I had to comment out `assure` to get it to compile, and I dont have your data file...) But you could use a similar method to get the real culprit.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** (Removed section about dereferencing `Trans`)

`Translen` might be your problem in this particular case. If it's less than 50, you're going to exceed the length of the `items` and `share` arrays during the `while(j<50)` loop in `getnextTransaction`. Jason's answer elaborates on this point.

Comment: The member access operator has higher precedence than the dereference operator, so the first syntax should be fine.

Comment: @Jason Thanks, I couldn't remember which it was but the syntax looked suspect. Updating my post now...